# Why this script is returning ' 'null' is not an object'?

Tags: javascript

Could you please point me in the right direction about why this script is returning `'null' is not an object`  ?

```
<script>
var pageDetailsSecond = "aaaaa";
if(pageDetailsSecond.match("&center=(.*)&zoom=").length) { 
    var mapSrc = pageDetailsSecond.match("&center=(.*)&zoom=");
    var mapSrc = mapSrc.split(",");
    var card_Latitude = mapSrc[0];
    var card_Longitude = mapSrc[1];
}
else {
    var card_Latitude = '';
    var card_Longitude = '';
}
</script>
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: `pageDetailsSecond.match("&center=(.*)&zoom=")` evaluates to `null` and then you're trying `null.length`. See http://jsfiddle.net/9wLkbnch/

Comment: @Felix Kling : Safari.

Comment: If I type `null.length` in Safari's console, I get `TypeError: 'null' is not an object (evaluating 'null.length')`.

Comment: How is `"&center=(.*)&zoom="` a RegExp? Should be `/&center=.*&zoom=/`.

Comment: @PHPglue: `.match()` converts the expression to a RegExp object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`"aaaaa".match("&center=(.*)&zoom=")` is null so, your `.length` call will fail.

Try changing your code to something like:

```
<script>
var pageDetailsSecond = "aaaaa";
var matches = pageDetailsSecond.match("&center=(.*)&zoom="); 
if(matches != null && matches.length > 1) { 
    var mapSrc = matches[matches.length - 1];
    var mapSrc = mapSrc.split(",");
    if(mapSrc.length == 2) {
        var card_Latitude = mapSrc[0];
        var card_Longitude = mapSrc[1];
    }
}
else {
    var card_Latitude = '';
    var card_Longitude = '';
}
</script>
```

Comment: The test can be `if (matches)`. Why must length be greater than 1?

Comment: @RobG Just being thorough, because on the next line there's an index access. (Trust and verify principle.)

Comment: If there are no matches, *matches* will be null. If there are any matches, its length will be at least 1. The above will skip the case where there is only one match (i.e. length is 1).

Answer (score 1):

`match` will return null if there's no match, and you can't write `null.length`. Actually, Chrome reports *TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of null*.

Here's a solution, along with a regex fix:

```
var pageDetailsSecond = "aaaaa";
var mapSrc = pageDetailsSecond.match("&center=(.+?),(.+?)&zoom=");
if (mapSrc) { 
    var card_Latitude = mapSrc[1];
    var card_Longitude = mapSrc[2];
} else {
    card_Latitude = '';
    card_Longitude = '';
}
```

I modified the regex so you don't have to `split` afterwards.

Answer (score 1):

There are two things you will have to fix here.

First, your conditional statement assumes a `.length` property, but the `.match()` method returns a `null` value when it does not find a match (and therefore, no `.length` property). Check out [this MDN page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) for details on `.match()`.

Second, in your regex you've grouped the matching `lat,lng` with `(.*)`. This means `.match()` will return an array with 2 matches - the first will match the entire expression, and the second will match your group:

```
["&center=34,-83&zoom=", "34,-83"]
```

You're interested in the second match. Here's a working example:

```
<script>
var pageDetailsSecond = "&center=34,-83&zoom=",
    matches = pageDetailsSecond.match("&center=(.*)&zoom=");

if(matches) {
    var mapSrc = matches[1].split(",");
    var card_Latitude = mapSrc[0];
    var card_Longitude = mapSrc[1];
}
else {
    var card_Latitude = '';
    var card_Longitude = '';
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `pageDetailsSecond.match("&center=(.*)&zoom=")` is `null` so it doesn't have the `length` property. So the error occurs when you try to check it's `length`.

Try this instead:

```
if(pageDetailsSecond.match("&center=(.*)&zoom=") !== null) {
```